# an example of a continuous function whose Fourier series diverges at a dense set of points

Tags: reference-request, fourier-series

Please give me a link to a reference for an example of a continuous function whose Fourier series diverges at a dense set of points. (given by Du Bois-Reymond). I couldn't find this in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments below, Kolmogorov's example is for a discontinuous function in $L^1$.

For a continuous function whose Fourier series diverges at all rational multiples of $2\pi$ (and hence on a dense set) see [Katznelson's book: An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_2_28?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=katznelson+harmonic+analysis&sprefix=katznelson+harmonic+analysis) Chapter 2, Remark after proof of Theorem 2.1. Note that the Fourier series of such a continuous function still converges almost everywhere by Carleson's theorem.

Comment: Why the function in Katznelson's book doesn't satisfy Fourier's Theorem? I know it is continuous but I suppose I can't derive it term by term to check if the derivate is piecewise continuous.

Comment: Carleson's theorem works for $p > 1$ only.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, such an almost-everywhere divergent Fourier series was constructed by Kolmogorov.

For an explicit example, you can consider a [Riesz product](http://books.google.com/books?id=W9AxAjSiIaUC&pg=PA302) of the form:

$$ \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left( 1+ i \frac{\cos 10^k x}{k}\right)$$

which is divergent. For more examples, see [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195523374) and [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1958-009-02/S0002-9939-1958-0096068-0/S0002-9939-1958-0096068-0.pdf).

---

Edit: (response to comment). Yes, you are right, du Bois Reymond did indeed construct the examples of Fourier series diverging at a dense set of points. However the result of Kolmogorov is stronger in that it gives almost everywhere divergence.

The papers of du Bois Reymond are:

> Ueber die Fourierschen Reihen

available for free download [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002515881) also another one [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN00224361X).

Comment: @George S. : It is given in this link http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Du_Bois-Reymond.html that Du Bois-Reymond gave such function.

Comment: @J.M. : I am not able to read them as they are not in english. Please suggest where to search for english versions. Also is the function given by Du Bois Reymond continuous everywhere ?

Comment: @J.M. : What is concept on which the result is based on ?

Comment: @Rajesh: Ask George; I only cleaned up his answer a bit.

Comment: @George. Kolmogorov's example is for an $L^1$ function, not continuous. By a famous theorem of Carleson, for a continuous function, the Fourier series converges almost everywhere.

Comment: @George. ...although the series may still diverge on a dense subset.

Comment: @TCL: Agree, $f$ continuous $\Rightarrow f\in L^2$.

Comment: @TCL : please give an example of such a function.

Comment: @Rajesh. I thought the above mentioned du Bois Reymond's example is one. Existence of such examples is also garunteed by Baire Category theorem.

Comment: @Rajesh: See Y. Katznelson,"An introduction to Harmonic Analysis" 2nd ed. p. 52.

Answer (score 9):

Kolmogorov improved his result to a Fourier series diverging everywhere. Original papers, in French:

Kolmogorov, A. N.: [Une série de Fourier-Lebesgue divergente presque partout](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm4/fm4127.pdf), *Fund. Math.*, 4, 324-328 (1923).

Kolmogorov, A. N.: [Une série de Fourier-Lebesgue divergente partout](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3136h/f1327.image), *Comptes Rendus*, 183, 1327-1328 (1926).