# $f_1, f_2 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ nonconstant, continuous, with period $1, \sqrt{2}$, respectively, then $f_1 + f_2$ is not periodic

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, irrational-numbers, periodic-functions

I've been working on this problem for several hours, but I keep getting stuck. Suppose $f_1, f_2 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ periodic with period $1, \sqrt{2}$, respectively, and that each of $f_1, f_2$ is nonconstant, continuous. Then $f_1 + f_2$ is not periodic.

My thoughts so far:

Suppose $p$ is the period of $f_1 + f_2$. I want to use the fact that $\{n\sqrt{2}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}/(x \sim x+p)$ to come up with a contradiction. I've tried numerous paths, which would take forever to write up. Now I'm just hoping to find the solution. I can provide more of my attempt if necessary.

Comment: I included that condition in my discussion, but I suppose I should add to title as well. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to see why this result doesn't hold if we don't assume continuity on $f_1, f_2$.

Comment: If continuity is not assumed, take $f_2$ to be a non-constant function that is both $1-$ and $\sqrt{2}-$ periodic (use the axiom of choice and define $f_2$ on group cosets modulo the additive subgroup ${\mathbb Z}+\sqrt{2}{\mathbb Z}$ of $\mathbb R$), and take $f_1$ to be any non-constant, $1$-periodic function.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: You don't need the axiom of choice there. Just let both $f_1$ and $f_2$ be the indicator function for $\mathbb Q+\sqrt2\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

Let us show the following property : if $f_1$ has period $T_1 > 0$,
$f_2$ has period $T_2 > 0$, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both continuous and
nonconstant, and $(T_1,T_2)$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$,
then $f=f_1+f_2$ cannot be periodic.

Your question is the case $T_1=1,T_2=\sqrt{2}$.

Suppose by contradiction that  $f$ has period $T>0$.
If $T$ is a rational multiple of $T_1$, then there are positive integers
$a$ and $b$ such that $aT=bT_1$. Let us call $S$ the number appearing on both sides
of this equality. Then $f$ and $f_1$ are both $S$-periodic ;
so is $f_2=f-f_1$. 
  Then $f_2$ has two ${\mathbb Q}$-linearly independent periods and is 
  continuous, which is possible only if $f_2$ is constant, contradicting the hypothesis.

So $T$ is not a rational multiple of $T_1$. Similarly, $T$ is not a 
rational multiple of $T_2$.

By the property shown in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517953/how-prove-this-nice-limit-lim-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-k-1nf-ka/523523#523523), we deduce that

$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x+kT_1)}{n}=
\int_{0}^{T} f(t) dt \tag{1} 
$$

But $f=f_1+f_2$ and

$$
\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_1(x+kT_1)}{n}=f_1(x) , \ \ 
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_2(x+kT_1)}{n}=
\int_{0}^{T_2} f_2(t) dt \tag{2} 
$$

This implies that

$$
\int_{0}^{T} f(t) dt = f_1(x)+ \int_{0}^{T_2} f_2(t) dt \tag{3}
$$

which contradicts the fact that $f_1$ is nonconstant. This finishes the
proof.