# Trying to prove that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \Sigma_{n=1}^N f(n\alpha) = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, equidistribution

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous periodic function with period 1. Show that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \Sigma_{n=1}^N f(n\alpha) = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$

The beginning (but probably not the end) of my confusion with this problem has to do with the irrational inputs. Why would that be necessary? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384765/prove-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty1-n-sum-n-1n-fnx-int-01ftdt?rq=1

Comment: If it's rational, then you only sample at a finite number of points (namely a number of points corresponding to the denominator of the rational number). For instance, if $\alpha = 1/2$, then $n\alpha \mod 1$ looks like $1/2, 0, 1/2, 0, ...$ By being irrational, this is really a statement about equidistribution.

Comment: @ForgotALot Yes, you can even say that it is a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @mixedmath You give in fact the hint to a probabilistic proof of the question...

Comment: Thank you for the help! Sorry about the redundancy, I did a search but wasn't able to find the question @ForgotALot linked to

Comment: @ForgotALot The answer is not complete, it can only be applied to the functions whose Fourier series converges uniformly, this is not true for all continuous functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) to conclude that the sequence $\{n\alpha\},n=1,2,\dots$ is equidistributed on the unit interval $[0,1]$ (note that we need the condition that $\alpha$ is irrational), where $\{n\alpha\}:=n\alpha-\lfloor n\alpha\rfloor$ is the fraction part of $n\alpha$. Then apply the Riemann integral criterion for equidistribution (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence)).