# Function not satisfying pointwise convergence and Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

Can you show an example of a function that does not satisfy pointwise convergence theorem hypotheses for Fourier series but that is still expressible as Fourier series?

[**Added** after comment]
In particular, I want to know if there is a function whose Fourier series converges but which does not satisfy the hypotheses of pointwise convergence theorem:

> Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has the following properties:
>
> $f$ has period $2 \pi$;
>
> $f$ is piecewise continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$;
>
> $D^{+}f$ and $D^{-}f$ exist.
>
> If f is continuous at $c$, then its Fourier series is equal to $f(c)$,
>   whereas if $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $c$, then its Fourier series is
>
> $$\frac{1}{2} \left[f(c^{+}) + f(c^{-}) \right].$$

Comment: What do you mean "still expressible as a Fourier series"? If a function is continuous on the circle, it admits a Fourier series expansion. [Such Fourier series expansion need not converge everywhere](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14855/an-example-of-a-continuous-function-whose-fourier-series-diverges-at-a-dense-set). Do you want to ask about a function whose Fourier series converges but which does _not_ satisfy the hypotheses of a particular pointwise convergence theorem? If so please specify which pointwise convergence theorem you are thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier series $\sum_n {e^{inx}\over (1+|n|)^{{1\over 2}+\epsilon}}$, with any positive epsilon, converges in $L^2$, but certainly does not converge pointwise at $0$ when $0<\epsilon<{1\over 2}$.

The series does converge at other points, but certainly not absolutely, and not *uniformly* pointwise.

Comment: What is the function from which this series comes?

Comment: @user411485, the function probably has no simpler alternative description than its Fourier expansion.

Comment: So I'm sure it's a Fourier series because of its "shape"?

Comment: @user411485, yes, the Fourier coefficients are square-summable, so, by Plancherel, it is/gives a function in $L^2$.