# A continuous function whose Fourier series diverges at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fourier-series, divergent-series, periodic-functions

I read this at many places such as wiki or elsewhere
quote :

---

It is possible to give explicit examples of a continuous function whose Fourier series diverges at $0$.

For instance, the even and $2π$-periodic function f defined for all $x$ in $[0,π]$ by

$$
{\displaystyle f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sin \left[\left(2^{n^{3}}+1\right){\frac {x}{2}}\right].}$$

---

I am confused by this.

If I plug in $x=0$ for $f(x)$ then I get

$$
{\displaystyle f(0)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sin \left[\left(2^{n^{3}}+1\right){\frac {0}{2}}\right]} = 0$$

Because the sine of zero is zero.

Also if I use the formula to compute the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$ I get exactly

$$
{\displaystyle f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{n^{2}}}\sin \left[\left(2^{n^{3}}+1\right){\frac {x}{2}}\right].}$$

So no contradiction there.

Notice the text said continuous, not differentiable.

Sure $f'(x)$ equals

$$
{\displaystyle f'(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {2^{n^{3}}+1}{n^{2}}}\sin [(2^{n^{3}}+1){\frac {x}{2}}]}$$

And that diverges.. euh for $x>0$.
But at $x=0$ it gives zero, again because sine of zero is zero.
So it seem to be not differentiable at zero.

But the cube root of $x$ is also not a differentiable at zero.
(although it does not jump from zero to infinity when going from zero to positive )

So I am very confused about this " counterexample "

And why this cubic term ?

Why not just any $f'(x)$ that diverges at zero such as

$$
{\displaystyle f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {3}{n^{2}}}\sin \left[\left(2^{n}+15\right){\frac {x}{2}}\right].}$$

??

I do not see how the series diverges at $0$ or the function is not equal to its Fourier series or anything like that.

I just see a non-differentiable function that is defined for all real $x$ because

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n^2}$$

converges and sine is always between $-1$ and $1$.

Im new to Fourier series as you might have guessed, so sorry for the dumb question maybe.

Comment: oh forgot to add a link.
Here is one : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence

Comment: The first thing you should observe is that this is *not* the representation of $f$ by its Fourier series, due to the $+1$ which makes the arguments inside of the sines non-integers.

Comment: @BrunoB but if we substitute $y = x/2$ ?

Comment: Well it wouldn't change anything about $f$? You would be looking at $y \mapsto f(2y)$, which has a different Fourier Series.

Comment: As referenced in the Wikipedia page, you can find an exercise about this function in *Les maths en tête* from Xavier Gourdon (page 262), the Analysis one not the Algebra one. (It's in French, but from the "euh" and the spaces before the punctuation it's safe for me to assume that you do speak French ;) ). I don't know the MSE policy for linking pdf files of *that kind* so I won't but it is available on the Internet if needed. Of course it won't replace a good old answer here but it might help you.

Comment: Ah, it seems like it was already discussed on here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3204166/1104384

Comment: Your $f'(x)$ is wrong (should have used $\sin'=\cos$).