# Fourier series divergent at any point

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I seek a function whose Fourier series is divergent in every point.
Thank you very much.

Comment: A function in which space? You cannot have an everywhere-divergent Fourier series for a $L^2$ function, for instance. This question - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14855/an-example-of-a-continuous-function-whose-fourier-series-diverges-at-a-dense-set - is deeply related.